# Access- Parameterized SQL statement with dropdown list input

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a parameterized SQL statement which takes a string as an input.

Instead, to avoid manual input error, I would like the user to be able to select the parameter value from a drop down list. I want the values of the drop down list to equal the distinct values in a column.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something? A distinct select on that column should be enough...

Answer (score 1):

Create a form with a combo, a OK command button and a Cancel  command button.
Refer to that combo in the condition of your query (use the wizard if you have trouble doing  that).
Have the Ok button open the query, and the Cancel button close its parent form.
The combo RowSource should contain your `SELECT DISTINCT`.